# Can't call Asp.net Webapi custom method using Postman

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, postman

I am trying to call custom name method name in webapi class. I am using Postman and able call `Get` method but not `CusActivity` method. Postman is not throwing any error either.

What is wrong here?

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "ApiWithAction",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);



public class CusActivityController : ApiController
{
    public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {
        return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public string CusActivityInsert(string userToken, string masterCustomerId, string activityText)
    {

    }

}
```

In POSTMAN

> http://localhost:52957/api/CusActivity/CusActivityInsert

```
{
"userToken": "userToken1",
"masterCustomerId": "3440214",
"activityText": "ID01-Membership."
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your API only has one parameter in config.

You need change `parameter` of your action API to

```
public string CusActivityInsert(UserToken item)
{

}
```

with class

```
public class UserToken
{        
        public string userToken { get; set; }
        public string masterCustomerId { get; set; }
        public string activityText { get; set; }
}
```

If you want to keep current parameter, change PostMan API URL to

http://localhost:56433/api/CusActivity/CusActivityInsert?userToken=userToken1&masterCustomerId=3440214&activityText=ID01-Membership.

Comment: How to allow multiple parameters in custom method? I need to pass multiple parameters

Comment: if you want to send JSON, need change to object in parameter